# celerybeat send task fails with ssl error

Tags: django, python-2.7, celery, celerybeat

I am using celerybeat to send periodic tasks to rabbitmq queue. It works as expected for some time and then send celery.backend_cleanup fails with SSL error.

```
[2016-10-24 04:00:02,309: DEBUG/MainProcess] Channel open
[2016-10-24 04:00:02,443: ERROR/MainProcess] Message Error: Couldn't apply scheduled task celery.backend_cleanup: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:1309: error:1409F07F:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_PENDING:bad write retry
['  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/bin/celery", line 9, in <module>\n    load_entry_point(\'celery-ipcat==3.1.23\', \'console_scripts\', \'celery\')()\n', '  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 30, in main\n    main()\n', '  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 81, in main\n    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)\n', '  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 793, in execute_from_commandline\n    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))\n', '  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 311, in execute_from_commandline\n    return self.handle_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:])\n', '  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 785, in handle_argv\n    return self.execute(command, argv)\n', '  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 717, in execute\n    ).run_from_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:], command=argv[0])\n', '  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 315, in run_from_argv\n    sys.argv if argv is None else argv, command)\n', '  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 377, in handle_argv\n    return self(*args, **options)\n', '  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 274, in __call__\n    ret = self.run(*args, **kwargs)\n', '  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/beat.py", line 79, in run\n    return beat().run()\n', '  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/apps/beat.py", line 83, in run\n    self.start_scheduler()\n', '  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/apps/beat.py", line 112, in start_scheduler\n    beat.start()\n', '  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 479, in start\n    interval = self.scheduler.tick()\n', '  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 221, in tick\n    next_time_to_run = self.maybe_due(entry, self.publisher)\n', '  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 207, in maybe_due\n    exc, traceback.format_stack(), exc_info=True)\n']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 204, in maybe_due
    result = self.apply_async(entry, publisher=publisher)
  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 260, in apply_async
    entry, exc=exc)), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 252, in apply_async
    **entry.options)
  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 565, in apply_async
    **dict(self._get_exec_options(), **options)
  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 354, in send_task
    reply_to=reply_to or self.oid, **options
  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 310, in publish_task
    **kwargs
  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 172, in publish
    routing_key, mandatory, immediate, exchange, declare)
  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 436, in _ensured
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 184, in _publish
    [maybe_declare(entity) for entity in declare]
  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 111, in maybe_declare
    return maybe_declare(entity, self.channel, retry, **retry_policy)
  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/common.py", line 113, in maybe_declare
    return _maybe_declare(entity, declared, ident, channel)
  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/common.py", line 120, in _maybe_declare
    entity.declare()
  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 521, in declare
    self.exchange.declare(nowait)
  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 174, in declare
    nowait=nowait, passive=passive,
  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/channel.py", line 615, in exchange_declare
    self._send_method((40, 10), args)
  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 56, in _send_method
    self.channel_id, method_sig, args, content,
  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/method_framing.py", line 221, in write_method
    write_frame(1, channel, payload)
  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 182, in write_frame
    frame_type, channel, size, payload, 0xce,
  File "/local/mnt/apps/ipcat/venvs/django16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 254, in _write
    n = write(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 172, in write
    return self._sslobj.write(data)
SchedulingError: Couldn't apply scheduled task celery.backend_cleanup: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:1309: error:1409F07F:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_PENDING:bad write retry
[2016-10-24 04:00:02,743: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 minutes.
```

After this failure all the subsequent send task fails with error as,

```
[2016-10-24 12:30:03,026: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Synchronizing schedule...
[2016-10-24 12:30:03,253: ERROR/MainProcess] Message Error: Couldn't apply scheduled task aggregate_hw_errata_sign_off_metrics_schedule: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'do_handshake'
```

I could disable celery.backend_cleanjob using CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = None but I am afraid, it might fails on other tasks configured.

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think, I found the problem. I was creating connection and was passing it to exchange and queue instance. I modified the code to let Queue and Exchange create connection to broker. so far no issues after this change.

Thanks

Old code:

```
from kombu import Connection, Queue, Exchange
conn = Connection(
                hostname=settings.BROKER_HOST,
                port=settings.BROKER_PORT,
                userid=settings.BROKER_USER,
                password=settings.BROKER_PASSWORD,
                virtual_host=settings.BROKER_VHOST,
                connect_timeout=BROKER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT,
                ssl=BROKER_USE_SSL,
                transport='pyamqp')
conn.connect()
channel = conn.channel()

exchange = Exchange('my.exchange', type='direct', passive=True, channel=channel)

CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('my.tasks', exchange=exchange, routing_key='my.metrics', channel=conn, passive=True),
)
```

New Code (fix):

```
from kombu import Queue, Exchange
exchange = Exchange('my.exchange', type='direct', passive=True)

CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('my.tasks', exchange=exchange, routing_key='my.metrics', passive=True),
)
```